# one method for using mongoose objects

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Solved by using query and passing it into DoSomethingWithDb:

```
var query = TestModel.findOne({numField: 1});
DoSomethingWithDb = function DoSomethingWithDb(dbMethod, callback, params) {
....
}
```

I would like to create one method to call like this:

```
this.DoSomethingWithDb(this.someObject.findOne, conditions, this.RegisterDBCallback, additionalParams);
```

Inside DoSomethingWithDb I try to execute query, but it raise error.

```
myboj.prototype.DoSomethingWithDb = function DoSomethingWithDb(dbMethod, conditions, callback, params) {
    dbMethod(conditions, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {

            return;
        }

        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback(doc, params);
        }

    });
};
```

Part of error callstack:

> ....node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:949
>   this._applyNamedScope(query);
>          ^ TypeError: Object # has no method '_applyNamedScope'
>       at findOne (...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\mode
>   l.js:949:8)
>       at DoSomethingWithDb (....server.js:2103:2)

Comment: you would generally add this as a static / instance method on your mongoose model. Please can you post your model code?

Comment: here full test code http://pastebin.com/0Qz52KzJ
I tryed to paste code here, but length of code is too long.

Comment: you shouldn't edit your question to put "solved" you need to answer it.

Comment: I can't find this green button :( Where it? http://snag.gy/9juiI.jpg

Comment: Scroll down... answer your own queston

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using query and passing it into DoSomethingWithDb:

```
var query = TestModel.findOne({numField: 1});
DoSomethingWithDb = function DoSomethingWithDb(query , callback, params) {
....
}
```